# Angular2 bundle.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: google-maps, angular, gulp, bundle

I use the 2.0.0-rc.4 version of Angular. I have always **"google is not defined"** problem  in my console

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiGD9.png)

```
bundle.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
With Angular Beta without gulp, I have not had the problem.
```

[typings folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW2rU.png)

my ** gulpfile.js** file

```
  var gulp = require('gulp');

    gulp.task('bundle', function() {
        var SystemBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');
        var builder = new SystemBuilder();

        builder.loadConfig('./system.config.js')
            .then(function(){
                var outputFile = 'dist/bundle.js';
                return builder.buildStatic('app', outputFile, {
                    minify: true,
                    mangle: true,
                    rollup: true
                });
            })
            .then(function(){
                console.log('bundle built successfully!');
            });
    });
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-poc",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "compile": "gulp compile",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && karma start",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify": "0.0.11",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.3.4",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2",
    "karma": "~0.13.15",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs2-launcher": "^0.3.2",
    "lite-server": "2.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.16",
    "traceur": "^0.0.91",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "yargs": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "events": "^1.0.2",
    "fbjs": "^0.3.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
```

}
}

**My tsd.json file**

```
   {
      "version": "v4",
      "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
      "ref": "master",
      "path": "typings",
      "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
      "installed": {
        "googlemaps/google.maps.d.ts": {
          "commit": "de82425735f84a10b43921ae4b1d085b3752a626"
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading these 2 files from your index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

For more details, refer this - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs

See if this helps.